# Taking Min and Max of Contigous Rows in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that looks something like this:

```
   ID  Value      Starts        Ends
0  A      1  2000-01-01  2000-06-01
1  A      2  2000-06-02  2000-12-31
2  A      1  2001-01-01  2001-06-01
3  A      1  2001-06-02  2001-12-31
```

What I want to do is collapse consecutive rows where there Id and value are the same. So ideally the output would be:

```
   ID  Value      Starts        Ends
0  A      1  2000-01-01  2000-06-01
1  A      2  2000-06-02  2000-12-31
2  A      1  2001-01-01  2001-12-31
```

However, if you naively take `np.min(Starts)` and `np.max(Ends)` it appears that (A,1) spans the values (A,2).

```
gb = df.groupby(['ID', 'Value'], as_index=False)
df = gb.agg({'Starts': np.min, 'Ends': np.max}, as_index=False)

  ID  Value      Starts        Ends
0  A      1  2000-01-01  2001-12-31
1  A      2  2000-06-02  2000-12-31
```

Is there an efficient way to get Pandas to do what I want?

Comment: Are you averse to adding an extra column?

Comment: Not in the slightest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a column (let's call it "extra") that increments each time the groupby category changes, you can groupby that instead. The challenge is then to make the addition of the new column efficient, and this is the most vectorized way I can think of to make it work.

```
increment = ((df.Value[:-1] != df.Value[1:]) | (df.ID[:-1] != df.ID[1:])).cumsum()
df["extra"] = pd.concat((pd.Series([0]),increment),ignore_index=True)
```

The first line takes the cumulative sum of a boolean array showing differing lines, then the second tacks on a zero at the front and adds it to the dataframe.

Then you can do

```
gb = df.groupby(['extra'], as_index=False)
df = gb.agg({'Starts': np.min, 'Ends': np.max}, as_index=False)
```